# appleAuthRequestResponse returning null for fullName and email

Tags: react-native, authentication

I am confused why me below snippet of code is showing null for email and fullName in console after user is authenticated successfully. I have read the documentation carefully and tried every possible thing I could. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
async function onAppleButtonPress() {
    // performs login request
    const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
      requestedOperation: AppleAuthRequestOperation.LOGIN,
      requestedScopes: [AppleAuthRequestScope.EMAIL, AppleAuthRequestScope.FULL_NAME],
    });
    //api getting current state of the user
    const credentialState = await appleAuth.getCredentialStateForUser(appleAuthRequestResponse.user);
    
    if (credentialState === AppleAuthCredentialState.AUTHORIZED) {
      // user is authenticated
      console.log("email is",appleAuthRequestResponse.email);
      console.log("full name is",appleAuthRequestResponse.fullName);
    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still retrieve the e-mail from the identityToken provided by `appleAuthrequestResponse` with any jwt decoder like [jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode)

```
    const {identityToken, nonce, email} = appleAuthRequestResponse
    const {email} = jwt_decode(identityToken)
    console.log(email)
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the same way for flutter sign_in_with_apple package. Using jwt_decoder package. When email, that returned from sign_in_with_apple was null.

Answer (score 3):

Apple only returns the full name and email on the first login, it will return null on the succeeding login so you need to save those data.

To receive these again, go to your device settings; `Settings > Apple ID, iCloud, iTunes & App Store > Password & Security > Apps Using Your Apple ID`, tap on your app and tap Stop Using Apple ID. You can now sign-in again and you'll receive the full name and `email.

Source [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication#faqs).

Comment: To receive these again, the steps are slightly different now: So, goto: Settings , then tap you name > Password & Security > Sign in with Apple > Tap your app > Press "Stop using Apple ID"

Comment: Not working. I had to change the simulator to make it working